# How shell parameters are parsed?

Tags: shell, gmp, msys, win32-process

I used this simple script,named *echo_arg* in a *msys* shell

```
echo $1
echo $2
echo $3
```

For these 2 cases, called from CLI,

1. `$ C:/msys/1.0/bin/sh.exe -c "C:/msys/1.0/bin/sh.exe echo_arg a "b" c"`
2. `$ C:/msys/1.0/bin/sh.exe -c "C:/msys/1.0/bin/sh.exe echo_arg a \"b\" c"`

the output was

```
a
b
c
```

**But** CreateProcess function in a C program did not give the same result (compilation with mingw-w64, thread : win32, exception : seh, version : 7.3.0 )

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
int i;
STARTUPINFO si;
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

ZeroMemory( &si, sizeof(si) );
si.cb = sizeof(si);
ZeroMemory( &pi, sizeof(pi) );

char * cmd[] = {
            "C:/msys/1.0/bin/sh.exe -c \"C:/msys/1.0/bin/sh.exe echo_arg a \"b\" c\"",  \
            "C:/msys/1.0/bin/sh.exe -c \"C:/msys/1.0/bin/sh.exe echo_arg a \\\"b\\\" c\"",  \
            "C:/msys/1.0/bin/sh.exe -c \"/bin/sh.exe echo_arg a \\\"b\\\" c\""  } ;

for (i=0;i<3;i++) {
    printf("\t%s\n",cmd[i]);
    CreateProcess(NULL, cmd[i] , NULL,NULL,FALSE,0,NULL,NULL,&si,&pi);
    WaitForSingleObject( pi.hProcess, INFINITE );
    CloseHandle( pi.hProcess );
    CloseHandle( pi.hThread ); }

}
```

Ouput :

*C:/msys/1.0/bin/sh.exe -c "C:/msys/1.0/bin/sh.exe echo_arg a "b" c"*
a
b
c

*C:/msys/1.0/bin/sh.exe -c "C:/msys/1.0/bin/sh.exe echo_arg a \"b\" c"*
a
b c

*C:/msys/1.0/bin/sh.exe -c "/bin/sh.exe echo_arg a \"b\" c"*
a
b
c

Why, in the second case, b and c are not separated ($2="b c" and $3 is empty) ? And why case 3 worked.

Only for information, I am not a mad man that likes to play with " \ \" / ... I have encountered this problem when I was trying to install GNU MP library (OS : windows 10). It did not work and it was the beginning of a long story before I found the cause.

Comment: CreateProcess has its own rules of parsing & matching quotes in command line. These do not necessarily are same as in posix sh.  Suggestion: use c++ and raw strings to type backslashes as is.

Comment: Is it possible to know the CreateProcess parsing rules ? I read some but it does not explain the output difference when **C:** is added.

Comment: Windows is mature and well supported product. It has documentation and forums (MSDN, Technet). If something does not work as documented, in your opinion, you're welcome to ask there.